# How to implement two dimensional object array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to implement a two-dimensional array using user input. I have a `Book` class. It has two variables: `int price` and `String name`. I want to store 5 books information in a two-dimensional array. `Book` class code is below:

```java
public class Book {
    String name;
    int price;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

`Main` Class code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int l = 5;
    Book[][] bk = new Book[l][l];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            // here i want to take user input.
            System.out.println("Enter Song: ");
            String sname = in.next();
            System.out.println("Enter price: ");
            int sprice = in.nextInt();
            // in this line i am getting type
            // error int can't convert to string
            song[i][j] = song[sname][price];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot use `sname` which of type `String` as index of array. if `sname` is int value in String, use `Integer.parseInt`

Comment: brother, how can I convert a book name to an integer? I want to input a book name and price in a two-dimensional array. so the name should be string and price should be int, double, or float.

Comment: This sounds like a place where Java.util.Dictionary Class  would be useful. The developer here might consider implementing a key (some unique integer or unique string, perhaps) so that you can collect the data more easily in a Dictionary, which consists of Key-Value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You never declared the array *song*, maybe you wanted to write

```
bk[i][j] = ...
```

Now you want to create a new "Book" for every *sname* and *sprice* that you read, so you have two options:

1) In each iteration create a new empty Book

```
Book tmp = new Book();
```

then you set his Name and his Price

```
tmp.setName(sname);
tmp.setPrice(sprice);
```

and then you assign the new Book to the current element of bk

```
bk[i][j] = tmp;
```

or

2) Add a constructor to the class Book that has Name and Price as parameters

```
public Book(String n, int p){
    name = n;
    price = p;
}
```

and use it to instantly create a new Book and assign it to the current element of bk

```
bk[i][j] = new Book(sname, sprice);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but what about bk[][] variable types?

Comment: @Almamun each element in bk is a Book, so it contains a name and a price

Comment: yes, I got that. but that way it doesn't work. then I define one-dimensional array Book bk[] = new Book[l]; and used only one for loop and then just set the value using the constructor. bk[i]= new Book(name,price);

Answer (score 1):

So what you require is `Book[String name][int price]`. That is not how 2D arrays work.

While declaring:

```java
int l = 5;
Book[][] bk = new Book[l][l];
```

You are implementing a 2D `Book` array that can have 25 book records.
1D array of `Book`s is sufficient for your requirements.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int l = 25;//any size you can have
    Book[] bk = new Book[l];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter Song: ");
        String sname = in.next();
        System.out.println("Enter price: ");
        int sprice = in.nextInt();
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setName(sname);
        book.setprice(sprice);
        bk[i] = book;
    }
}
```